# Parsing a DateTime string in C# with strange characters

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a dateTime string as follows `"\"2017-09-20T02:55:15.000Z\""`. I want to parse it in C#.

```
DateTime gpsddt
string date = "\"2017-09-20T02:55:15.000Z\"";
var result = DateTime.TryParse(date, out gpsddt);
```

result is false. I don't know how to parse the above string. I got this string from a `gpsd` daemon. I can't find any format specifier that matches this datetime string [here](http://www.code-sample.net/CSharp/Format-DateTime)

Comment: There are extra double quotes at the start and end of the date value. Remove them using Trim and then try parsing.

Answer (score 2):

The string is currently `"2017-09-20T02:55:15.000Z"`, but it needs to be `2017-09-20T02:55:15.000Z` to parse correctly. As @Chetan suggested in the comment, you need to strip out the `"` characters.

Add this line before parsing.

```
date = date.Replace("\"", "");
```

Alternatively, the DateTime.TryParseExact allows you to specify the source format. However it does require you to consider a lot more factors such as culture and style to use as well.

```
result = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "\"\\\"\"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ\"\\\"\"", new CultureInfo("en-AU"), DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out gpsddt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple matter of doing this:

```
DateTime gpsddt;
string date = "\"2017-09-20T02:55:15.000Z\"";
var result = DateTime.TryParse(date.Trim('"'), out gpsddt);
```